# постепенная печать python

Tags: python

Хочу сделать текст, который постепенно будет печатать содержимое. То есть например в слове "Ожидание..." точки должны выводится одна за другой раз в секунду. Пытался сделать так:

```
from time import sleep

print("Ожидание" + sleep(1) + "." + sleep(1) + "." + sleep(1) + ".")
```

Но к сожалению это не работает. Как сделать что-то наподобие этого?

Comment: `print("Ожидание", end="", flush=True); sleep(1); print(".", end="", flush=True); sleep(1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from time import sleep

print("Ожидание", end="")

for i in range(3):
    sleep(1)
    print(".", end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep

print("Ожидание", end='', flush=True)
for _ in range(3):
    sleep(1)
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
```

В таком случае буфер вывода не будет ожидать перехода на следующую строку и печатать все в один момент.